# MySQL - Multiple inner joins and concat

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a database, here are the tables I need:

- special_issues
- journals
- journal_editors

The structure is like described here:

- I have special issues, each special issue belongs to a journal, so in the table special_issue, I have the journal_id
- For each journal, I have editors (one or more). This info can be obtained from the journal_editors table by matching the editors for the specific journal_id.

What I would like to get is for each special issue, the journal editors of the journal this special issue belongs.

For that, I would like to concat the id's, so at the end I will have something like this:

```
special issue    editors
     si1         1,5,10
     si2         14,25,5
```

Etc...

I tryied that:

```
SELECT si.name, CONCAT(users.firstname,' ', users.lastname) AS journal_editors
FROM `special_issues` si
INNER JOIN journal_editors jeds ON si.journal_id = journal_id
WHERE si.journal_id =1 GROUP BY si.name"
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT si.name, GROUP_CONCAT(users.firstname,' ', users.lastname) AS journal_editors 
FROM special_issues si 
INNER JOIN journal_editors jeds ON si.journal_id = journal_id 
WHERE si.journal_id =1 
GROUP BY si.name
```

[Manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: One question tombom, I added another inner join in the quey and now, my journal_editors is duplicated. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm afraid it's a bit hard to understand what you mean. Does a distinct fix the problem? Like `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(users.firstname, ' ', users.lastname))`. If not, post the query please.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT si.name, GROUP_CONCAT(users.firstname,' ', users.lastname) AS journal_editors
  FROM `special_issues` si
 INNER 
  JOIN journal_editors jeds ON si.journal_id = jeds.journal_id
 WHERE si.journal_id =1 
 GROUP BY si.name
```